# rsync for mirror server with plesk

Tags: backup, centos, rsync, plesk, mirror

I have 2 linux server (centOS) with Plesk 10 and two license. I want to make the first server master and the second a mirror slave, using RSYNC.

I know how to transfer some folders (domains and databases).. but I have a question:

*If I create a new domain on the master server, how can I "update" the slave server?*

If I use rsync the **vhosts** folder and **mysql** folder.. the slave plesk doesn't know that I have added a new domain..

I have to rsync the **psa** folder too?

Someone can help me to find all the folders "to rsync" from the master server to the slave server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to vhosts and mysql you would need to replicate

- Plesk managing DB ("psa")
- DNS configuration
- /etc/psa, /etc/httpd and /etc/proftpd*

There may be some other folders as well - you may need to watch changes for a while